# Convert output of tf.nn.top_n into a sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

As the title states, I'm trying to extract the highest n elements per row from a matrix in tensorflow, and store the result in a sparse Tensor.

I've been able to extract the indices and values with tf.nn.top_n, but the indices don't follow the convention required by tf.SparseTensor.

Specifically, tf.nn.top_n returns a matrix of col indices with the same shape as the resulting value matrix (Rows x n), whereas tf.SparseTensor wants a (# non-zero x 2) matrix with 1 row per non-zero element and the columns holding the row and col indices.

The values can an analogous problem whereby a list of non-zero elements is desired instead of a matrix of values.

**How can I quickly convert between these indexing notation schemes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable with a bit of modular arithmetic. Here's an example that works on matrices, although it would be possible to loop over more axes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def slices_to_dims(slice_indices):
  """
  Args:
    slice_indices: An [N, k] Tensor mapping to column indices.
  Returns:
    An index Tensor with shape [N * k, 2], corresponding to indices suitable for
    passing to SparseTensor.
  """
  slice_indices = tf.cast(slice_indices, tf.int64)
  num_rows = tf.shape(slice_indices, out_type=tf.int64)[0]
  row_range = tf.range(num_rows)
  item_numbers = slice_indices * num_rows + tf.expand_dims(row_range, axis=1)
  item_numbers_flat = tf.reshape(item_numbers, [-1])
  return tf.stack([item_numbers_flat % num_rows, 
                   item_numbers_flat // num_rows], axis=1)
```

Example usage:

```
dense_shape = [5, 7]
dense_matrix = tf.random_normal(shape=dense_shape)
top_values, top_indices = tf.nn.top_k(dense_matrix, k=2)
sparse_indices = slices_to_dims(top_indices)
sparse_tensor = tf.sparse_reorder(tf.SparseTensor(
    indices=sparse_indices, 
    values=tf.reshape(top_values, [-1]),
    dense_shape=dense_shape))
densified_top = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_tensor)
with tf.Session() as session:
  sparse_top, dense_original, dense_selected = session.run(
      [sparse_tensor, dense_matrix, densified_top])
  print(dense_original)
  print(dense_selected)
  print(sparse_top)
```

Prints:

```
[[ 1.44056129 -1.01790774 -0.2795608   2.34854746 -2.27528405 -0.62035948
   3.36598897]
 [ 0.7114948  -0.42564821 -0.93446779 -0.25373486 -0.51730365  0.72331643
  -0.75625718]
 [-0.6501748  -0.92748415 -0.95409006 -0.07157528  0.80637723 -0.32177576
  -1.4516511 ]
 [-1.081038   -0.67226124 -1.19455576  0.44537872 -0.69019234 -0.61539739
   0.15328468]
 [ 0.43032476 -0.11295394  0.83491379 -0.67906654  0.20325914 -0.0155068
   0.52107805]]
[[ 0.          0.          0.          2.34854746  0.          0.
   3.36598897]
 [ 0.7114948   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.72331643
   0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         -0.07157528  0.80637723  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.44537872  0.          0.
   0.15328468]
 [ 0.          0.          0.83491379  0.          0.          0.
   0.52107805]]
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 3],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 6],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 6]]), values=array([ 2.34854746,  3.36598897,  0.7114948 ,  0.72331643, -0.07157528,
        0.80637723,  0.44537872,  0.15328468,  0.83491379,  0.52107805], dtype=float32), dense_shape=array([5, 7]))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I was worried that methods like this would incur too much overhead, but it seems quite snappy. Thanks!